# QGIS Zoom Level with OpenStreetMap Data

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

how can I increase the zoom level in QGIS for OpenStreetMap (OSM) data? I am new to GIS therefore I may have the terminology wrong. I have added an OSM layer using the OpenLayers plugin. Everything is working fine except once I zoom in too much, the layer disappears. I need to be able to zoom very close. How can I achieve this? I have tried importing shapefiles instead and it does let me zoom in however, it does not look the same as the openstreetmaps.com website. Is there a way to basically copy this data and be able to zoom in very close and have the same style (meaning the colors, width of roads, buildings, etc.)? 1:1 scale would be great!

Comment: Yes, you are correct, my apologies. I have edited my question as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The Openlayers plugin is restricted to a scale of 1:2500

Alternatively, you can use the TileLayerPlugin. It works with a tab-delimited text file for the available datasources.

For Openstreetmap tiles, the additional entry is:

```
Openstreetmap   OSM http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png 1   0   19  -180    -85.0   180.0   85.0
```

Keep in mind that the delimiters have to be tabs, not blanks.

Comment: You may have mentioned that this file (saved as .tsv in UTF8) should go to .qgis2/python/plugins/TileLayerPlugin/layers. It works, but the OSM labels are too small to be readable. Is there maybe also a way to add this via qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer in the python console ? (Just guessing)

Comment: You can place the file anywhere you want. The path can be chosen in the plugins form with the `Settings` icon. For the python console, I can not help you further.

Comment: Perfect! That works! Although the text does get blurry. I'm assuming because they are downloaded as PNGs or Bitmaps instead of SVG graphics?

Comment: yes, tiles are typically pngs, not svgs.

Comment: If you stick to EPSG:3857, the text will look better.